# NextJS get server side props once only?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I'd like to do a server side data query but only one time when a person logs into a website. The data will be passed down to the frontend and stored in a context so further navigations via next/link will preserve this existing data.

The basic premise is I have a user with account details (username, display photo, etc) - I want to query all this data *once* via the server and store that data in the browser (using react contexts) to avoid having to refetch the data between page navigations.

I looked into getStaticProps but that won't do it for me as the data is very dynamic and user specific, the other idea I had was for the application to be aware it has the data and include a query param like "dontFetchData=true" so taht subsequent navigations don't unecessarily refetch data the client already has.

Is that a reasonable solution or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Is there no session or log out on this application?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there is no possibility to do this.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18210